# Build action for sql script files in database projects (*.sqlproj)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

For a sql script file in a database project, is there anything to be gained by using a `Build Action` of `Build` or `Compile`? I usually just use `None`, but wonder if `Build` or `Compile` do anything for a sql script e.g. perhaps some sort of additional syntax checking?

(We use our own custom deployment for scripts, so deployment options are not required.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is nothing to compile, just use None...

Answer (score 4):

When performing a schema compare, only .sql files with their build action set to `Build` are included.

Answer (score 3):

If you are building the project, creating a dacpac and then using sqlpackage.exe to deploy the dacpac to the server. Then setting the build action to none on a script will ensure that the script is not included in the update to the server. It give you8 a way to control what updates are carried out thru this tooling.